# Graphing an average of existing data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

The the graph I wish to emulate is this:

[image]

The graph I have now is this:

[image]

What kind of geom would I use to emulate the black line in the first chart?

I am currently using geom_smooth but am aware I might be on the wrong track:

```
p <- ggplot(df_test1, aes(time, reading))
p + geom_point(alpha = 1/4, colour = "#7F0019")+geom_smooth(colour = "black")+
  scale_x_date(breaks="month", labels=date_format("%b"))
```

Using geom_line results in the following chart:

[image]

Comment: Maybe rolling means/medians?

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840761/add-moving-average-plot-to-time-series-plot-in-r

Comment: Yes, in a way. I've looked at it and am working on answering my own particular question with an implementation of that answer.