# How to use a weighted moving average with geom_smooth in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I would like to use a weighted average smoother in `ggplot2::geom_smooth()` but it is not one of the permitted options for `method =`. Is the way to do it to calculate the smoothed values and add it as a layer on my ggplot scatterplot?

Sample data:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- seq(0, 50, 0.1)
prob <- - x*(x - 50)/1000
tmp_df <- data.frame(x, prob)
tmp_df <- tmp_df[rep(1:nrow(tmp_df), times = 10),]
tmp_df$success <- rbinom(n = nrow(tmp_df), size = 1, prob = tmp_df$prob)
```

And using `method = 'gam'` on this data:

```
ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x = x, y = success)) +
    geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2), size = 0.1) +
    geom_smooth()
```

producing:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840761/add-moving-average-plot-to-time-series-plot-in-r ?

Comment: That's more or less what `method = 'loess'` does, if I understand what you want.

Comment: what are the weights? the probabilities of success?